# Events on children of contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
myDiv.bind('keypress', '> *', function(event) { console.log('keypress') });
```

but it does not seem to work.

myDiv is contenteditable and I am trying to get access to p elements that are being edited.

http://jsfiddle.net/nb5UA/5/ (try typing within the div created after you click enter)

Comment: Post a demo. Your code should work.

Answer (score 7):

> This is barely possible with **`contenteditable`** seeing as the elements do not hold input like events and therefore do not have real focus, so you can't actually determine the **`event.target`**. The **`event.target`** will always be the container that has the attribute 
>   `contenteditable="true"`.
>
> However you can use the **`DOMCharacterDataModified`** event like the example & demo below.

```
$('#test').on('DOMCharacterDataModified',  function( event ) {
    if($(event.target).parent().attr('id') === 'test') { // Reference 1 
        alert('modified');
    }
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nb5UA/15/**

> **Reference 1:** The **`if`** statement is checking that the **`event.target`** is a direct child of the `#test` container.

The browser support for **`DOMCharacterDataModified`** is not bad. **< IE9** is not supported, and I can't find much info on the event so if anyone has a good resource for it, please share in the comments.

Comment: But children are added dynamically.

Comment: @Nonconformist Then why didn't you say that in your question?

Comment: @Doorknob The question mentions `contenteditable`. That seems a decent suggestion of dynamic content.

Comment: Mutation Events like DOMCharacterDataModified have been deprecated in favor of Mutation Observers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 1):

The issue may not be the selector, but rather that the `<div id="test">` is always the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
$('#test').on('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

With this, at least in Chrome, the console just logs:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px; overflow: scroll; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">...</div>
...
```

Comment: This seems to be correct. OP's selectors are fine (`click` instead of `keypress` works), the problem is that keyboard events are only handled on the top level of a `contenteditable` element.

Comment: Yeah, like i explained in my answer, the reason it is always the `test` element is because that is the only element that has any focus.

Answer (score -1):

Keypress event will bubble up to the container element, so you don't necessarily need bind to the children. Instead bind only to the container, than you can check which element was edited by accessing to the event.target property.

```
$('#container').on('keypress', function (event) { alert(event.target) });
```