# How to delete entire hyperlink when backspace or delete button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am building a hashtag-to-hyperlink converter. This works completely fine. The end result will look like this:

My love for you is  [#big](https://google.com)  when I'm with someone else.

However if the user presses **backspace** behind the hyperlink and corrects the text of the hashtag, he will start typing inside of the hyperlink, making the entire following text a hyperlink, and therefore blue:

My love for you is  [#bigger when I'm with someone else](https://google.com)

If I use *contenteditable="false"*, my Firefox browser will prevent me from even pressing backspace when I reach the hyperlink. Then the hyperlink won't delete at all:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    My love for you is 
        <a contenteditable="false" href="https://google.com" >#big</a> 
    when I'm with someone else.
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to delete the entire hyperlink when the user presses **backspace** or **delete** in JQuery? Therefore the endresult must look like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    My love for you is  when I'm with someone else.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle this is by using an event listener. My initial thought was to use an event like `keypress` or `keydown`, but as [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169626/events-on-children-of-contenteditable-element) says, those events will always attach to the `contenteditable` element, NOT any child elements. So it's very difficult to tell if the edit happened inside of an anchor tag.

But as that linked answer also mentions, the `DOMCharacterDataModified` event WILL attach to the child elements. This is the solution I finally arrived at.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.edit');
div.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', function(e) {
  if (e.newValue.length >= e.prevValue.length) return;
  var target = e.target
  if (target instanceof Text) target = target.parentElement;
  var atag = target.closest('.edit > a');
  if (atag) div.removeChild(atag);
});
```

```html
<div class='edit' contenteditable="true">
  My love for you is <a href="https://google.com">#big</a> when I'm with someone else.
</div>
```

Some notes:

- Have to check for a `#text` node, because it doesn't have the `closest` method like an `Element` does.
- Then I can use the `closest` method to see if it's an anchor tag which is a direct descendant of the `contenteditable` element (I added a class name to the element to make it a little simpler).
- There is no good way to know what key may have been pressed. The simplest approach seemed to be comparing the length of `newValue` and `prevValue` to see if it's shorter than it was. If so, assume a backspace/delete happened.
- However there are other ways the value could become shorter, notably if someone highlights more than one character and then replaces it by typing a single character. If this is an issue then the solution would need to be more complicated to take this into account.

Tested in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What if my contenteditable div is rendered dynamically? What would be the solution?

Comment: You could either add the event to a higher DOM element (with proper filtering such as I'm doing with `.closest` in my example, to make sure it doesn't affect other child elements), or you could add it to the `div` when it is created. I'm partial to the first method, but either would work.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly fine! I did atag.remove() instead. Since I was getting "Node not found" error